# Does Hazelcast have a gateway between adjacent networks

Tags: hazelcast

I'm trying to create a 3 node Hazelcast cluster with 2 nodes in 2 adjacent networks connected over a node connected to both networks acting as a gateway. Is this possible? So far I get error messages saying the 2 nodes can't connect which is as it should be. Can I tell them to always communicate over the 3rd node?

Comment: Please add the exact error messages, this helps with answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast cluster members (or nodes as you call them) are not routers or gateway to one another, all members must be able to detect each other to form the cluster. A user/app has no control over which member it can talk to; for example, a distributed caching operation goes to the member that hosts the data in that operation and this process is not exposed to apps/clients.

For a user, a cluster may be perceived as a service.